# Reporting Services - Calculating row totals/percentages in a table

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to calculate totals for each row as well as a percentage of the overall total.

Right now I have a table like this:

```
Blah    Col1    Col2    Col3
-----------------------------
ABC      1        1      1
DEF      2        2      3
-----------------------------
Total    3        3      4
```

And I want it to include totals/percentages like so:

```
Blah    Col1    Col2    Col3    Total    %
--------------------------------------------
ABC      1        1      1        3     30%
DEF      2        2      3        7     70%
--------------------------------------------
Total    3        3      4        10    100%
```

I know I can do the calculations in the SQL query, but the stored procedure is rather complicated so I'd like to avoid that if possible. So I'm wondering if there's a simple way to achieve this in SSRS.

Right now I just have a row group for each `Blah` which I use to calculate column totals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To calculate the total, just do a simple sum using the `+` operator. For the percentage, you can refer to the grand total using `ReportItems!ItemName`.

Answer (score 14):

I added a Totals Row for my matrix, then I referenced the totals textbox (textbox 8 in my case) for the column and I did:

```
Sum(Fields.FieldName.Value)/ReportItems!Textbox8.Value
```

I hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregate functions in Reporting Services like "SUM" and "AVG" to achieve what you are trying to do.  The way it works is "Detail" parts of groups in SSRS tables will list all of the data, while non-detail parts (like headers and footers) of groups can be used for aggregates like:

```
=SUM(Fields!TestValue.Value)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159134%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: What if I wanted to sum certain rows and not all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Create two groups, one on a column that is the same data for each row, then one on column blah.  add a row for the emcompassing group and do a sum there.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do as following:
Sum(CInt(Fields!TestValue.Value))
 or Sum(CInt(Fields!DollarAmountOfCheck.Value),"DataSet1") 
sometime when data is coming through WCF, it does not accept Sum() function. but this works fine in that case.